# Is there any limitations to send data with help of webservices from iphone app?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, web-services, xamarin.ios

I am working on xamarin ios. I am using webservices to get the data and post the data. When I am trying to upload large data nothing happens. In that case service call never reach on server. If I upload few data then it works fine.

So I just want to confirm is there any limitation to upload data from Iphone app with help of webservices? If not then what may be the cause that in case of large data my service call never reach on server?

Comment: Could provide some examples of the way you've coded the calls to the web service, and preferably an example with a small amount of data, and one with a large amount of data, so that we can see you are performing the calls correctly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> **For [RESTful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) service**:
>   There is no limit for POST & PUT type of request, while sending data
>   with web service. But if you use, GET type of request, then there is
>   limit of data with request.

For GET, limit of data size, depends on type of server.
 
- For Tomcat - default is 2MB ([Upgradable**](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html))
 
- For PHP - default is 2MB ([Upgradable**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size))
 
- For Apache - default is 2MB ([Upgradable**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody))

**Upgradable: For more details, click on links.

[Oracle - Web service development guideline](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/web.1111/e15184/rest.htm#WSCPT230)

**Note:**

- If you are uploading large size of files, then use Multipart Upload method/technique to send your data to web server.
- Check request time out interval set with web service request. Large size data require more time than normal request.
- Use asynchronous requests, that works in background state for application, for better data transmission, without interrupting user interaction with content of application UI elements.

Comment: So could you tell me the reason, why my service call never reach on server if sending heavy data?

Comment: Please share more details about your web service request (source code). Check request time out interval. Use multipart upload technique, if you want to send large size of files with your web service request.

Comment: I have data in xml format. There are multiple list items in xml. If the list items increases to 100-200 items then it doesn't upload and never reach the server. I have a service method in which I am passing the xml as an object. The problem I found that in this that after calling the service method from my code, but it lost somewhere and never call the service method, I tried to track on webservice but found that the service call from my code never reach there. So do you have any idea where it losts between calling from my code and reaching server?